# Define variables a and b in matrix with determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I should calclulate the determinant of a Matrix (4x4) and define the pairs if $a$ and $b \in R$.

I calculated this determinant: $ab\left(a-2b\right)\left(2a+b\right),$ but how can I use the determinant to define $a$ and $b$ such that A is invertible?

Comment: You forgot to include the matrix.

Comment: "... define pairs if $a$ and $b \in R$ such that ...... ?

Comment: You need the determinant to be different from $0$, hence $a\neq 0$, $b\neq 0$, $a\neq 2b$ and $b\neq -2a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall inverse of a matrix = $\frac{1}{det(A)}adj(A)$

So, for invertible matrix  $ab\left(a-2b\right)\left(2a+b\right)\neq0$

Therefore $a\neq 0 , b\neq 0, a\neq 2b \text{ and } b\neq −2a. $

Comment: what means adj(A)?

Comment: adjoint of matrix.

Comment: $a≠0,b≠0,a≠2b$ and $b≠−2a$ there are a lot of posibilites with this, is that everything I have to do?

Comment: Yes, any one of these being equal to zero will make your determinant zero hence non-invertible function. You have to consider each and every possibility.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is invertible $ \iff ab\left(a-2b\right)\left(2a+b\right) \ne 0.$

Can you proceed ?